# How to set class-scope constants in ruby?

Tags: ruby, constants

Super-beginner easy points ruby question.  I'm trying to learn some ruby by programming the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problems.  So I have a test

```
class ProjectEuler_tests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  @solution = 123456 # Not the answer so as not to be a spoiler
  def test_problem_1
    assert_equal(@solution, ProjectEuler1.new.solve)
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work, @solution is nil when the test runs.  What is the proper way to assign it at the class scope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Class constants](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html) in ruby start with an uppercase char:

```
class ProjectEuler_tests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  SOLUTION = 123456 # Not the answer so as not to be a spoiler
  def test_problem_1
    assert_equal(SOLUTION, ProjectEuler1.new.solve)
  end
end
```